# Javascript XMLHttpRequest send has no effect

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I am attempting to transfer a file to a Javascript pgm, using XMLHttpRequest. What I observe is that the XMLHttpRequest.send(null) doesn't seem to have any effect. If I use asynchronous XMLHttpRequest, as in the code below, the script completes and the text in the body is displayed. If I use synchronous XMLHttpRequest, by setting the 3rd arg of XMLHttpRequest.open to false (default is true), the script also completes and displays the text in the body. So it is behaving as if the .send call has no effect.

This probably means I have an error in the code or location of the file. The code is in an HTML file, and test.txt is in the same directory. I am using Firefox 3.6.13 to open the HTML file locally (i e, with the File/Open File... menu item).

This is what I see in the alerts:
Asynchronous (point:readyStatus): 7:0, 8:0, 1:1, 6, 9:1
Synchronous: 7:0, 8:0, 9:1

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to what is wrong, or how to debug it further.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(data)
{
    alert(data);
}

function handlerQ()
{
    alert("point 1 readyState="+this.readyState);
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        // so far so good
       alert("point 2");
       if(this.responseXML != null && this.responseXML.getElementById('test').firstChild.data)
       // success!
       {
           alert("point 3");
           test(this.responseXML.getElementById('test').firstChild.data);
       }
       else
       {
           alert("point 4");
           test(null);
       }
    }
    else if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status != 200)
    {
        // fetched the wrong page or network error...
       alert("point 5");
       test(null);
    }
    alert("point 6");
}

var clientQ = new XMLHttpRequest();
alert("point 7 readyState="+clientQ.readyState);
clientQ.onreadystatechange = handlerQ;
alert("point 8 readyState="+clientQ.readyState);
clientQ.open("GET", "test.txt",false); // asynchronous
alert("point 9 readyState="+clientQ.readyState);
clientQ.send(null);
alert("point 10 readyState="+clientQ.readyState);

</script>
</head>
<body>
This is the body
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch file from the local file system you need to compare result status to 0 for success instead of 200 which is for HTTP requests. Also please make sure your `test.txt` is XML file.